# About passing around Tcl arrays holding lists

Tags: tcl

First off: I could fix my problem by myself, but I don't understand why my original solution did not work, and this is what I am interested in. I tried to make a compact example here:

I am dynamically building arrays, each array value being a list. Let's start with the following program:

```
# 'collector' is a callback function, expecting a container array, and some 
# data used to populate the array.
proc generate { collector arr_name } {
  eval $collector $arr_name first XXX YYY
  eval $collector $arr_name second UUU VVV
}

# This is the callback function used in our example
proc collect { container_name key valuex valuey } {
  upvar $container_name container
  lappend container($key) [list $valuex $valuey]
}

# Procedure to write out an array
proc dump { arr_name } {
  upvar $arr_name arr
  puts $arr_name:
  foreach key [array names arr] {
    puts "$key : $arr($key)"
  }
}

# Main program
array set containerA {}
generate [namespace code { collect }] containerA
dump containerA
```

Up to this point, nothing spectacular. Running this program produces the output

```
containerA:
second : {UUU VVV}
first : {XXX YYY}
```

But now let's extend this program somewhat

```
# Wrapper function to call 'generate' using a fixed collector function
# ("Currying" the first argument to generate)
proc coll_gen { container_name } {
  upvar $container_name container
  generate [namespace code { collect }] $container_name ; # This works
  # This would not work:
  #generate [namespace code { collect }] container
}

array set containerB {}
coll_gen containerB
dump containerB
```

As written here, this would work too, and we get the output

```
containerB:
second : {UUU VVV}
first : {XXX YYY}
```

Now to my question: As you already can guess from the comments in the code, I had first written coll_gen as

```
proc coll_gen { container_name } {
  upvar $container_name container
  generate [namespace code { collect }] container
}
```

My reasoning was that, since container is an alias to the array, the name of which was passed via the parameter list, I could equally well pass on the name of this alias to the 'generate' function. However, when I run the code (Tcl 8.5), it turns out that containerB is empty.

Why is it that it didn't work this way too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is one of evaluation scope.

Let's write out the call stack at the point where you're inside `collect` in the case where things don't work:

```
::
   coll_gen containerB
      generate {namespace inscope :: { collect }} container
         namespace inscope :: { collect } container first XXX YYY
            collect container first XXX YYY
```

Whoops! What's that `namespace inscope`? Where are the inner layers `upvar`ing to? The result of `namespace code` is a wrapping with `namespace inscope` (which you shouldn't write directly; use `namespace code` or `namespace eval`) that arranges for the script formed by appending the other arguments (with appropriate metacharacter protection) to be run in the given namespace (`::` in your case, I assume). This “run in the given namespace” requires adding another stack frame, and that's what the `upvar` is then poking into (it's probably created a global array called `container`, since the `namespace inscope` frame is a namespace-coupled one, not a “procedure local” stack frame).

You could use `upvar 2` or maybe even `upvar 3` (I'm not quite sure which) inside `collect` to work around this, but that's horrific and fragile.
You're better off writing your code like this:

```
proc coll_gen { container_name } {
    upvar $container_name container
    generate [namespace which collect] container
}
proc generate { collector arr_name } {
    upvar 1 $arr_name collectorVar
    eval $collector collectorVar first XXX YYY
    eval $collector collectorVar second UUU VVV
}
```

With that, the call stack will become this:

```
::
   coll_gen containerB
      generate ::collect container
         ::collect collectorVar first XXX YYY
```

Annotating with what the array is called inside each level…

```
::                                              ### containerB
   coll_gen containerB                          ### container (→ containerB)
      generate ::collect container              ### collectorVar (→ container → containerB)
         ::collect collectorVar first XXX YYY   ### container (→ collectorVar → container → containerB)
```

Comment: `upvar 2` and above are usually a sign that you're Doing It Wrong, as it makes the code far more rigid than it ought to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is interesting to compare your solution to that of Hoodiecrow. With my background, I find yours easier to understand, but this could be because I'm coming from the Ruby/Perl/Python side an am not used yet to see variables as "just strings". If you look at your solution, and to that of Hoodiecrow, which one would you consider more "Tcl-ish"?

Comment: @user1934428: heh. I dabble in Tcl; Donal is one of the *implementors* of Tcl. I'd think that answers your question `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Tcl is very literal, and I find it helps to think in terms of strings as far as possible, similar to how you think in terms of symbols when using Lisp but even more pervasive. When you use `upvar`, what you get isn't anything like a reference variable in some other languages. You just get to refer to a Tcl_Obj that was originally referenced in another stack frame (or the same stack frame if you `upvar 0`) using a local name. In the invocation

```
generate [namespace code { collect }] container
```

the second argument to `generate` doesn't carry over any kind of reference to the Tcl_Obj that `container` referred to inside `coll_gen`: the argument is just a Tcl_Obj containing the string "container". If that string is equal to a valid name in one of the stack frames, you can `upvar` the name to get/be able to set a value in the associated object (and if you've managed the stack frames correctly, it will even be the object you wanted to access).

The commands `upvar` and `uplevel` have important uses, but you really don't need them here. If you just go with *names* and don't try to drag your objects with you through each stack frame, your code becomes easier to read and easier to maintain:

```
proc generate args {
    # use  eval $args first XXX YYY  if you have Tcl 8.4 or earlier
    {*}$args first XXX YYY
    {*}$args second UUU VVV
}

proc collect {container_name key args} {
  lappend ${container_name}($key) $args
}

proc dump arr_name {
  puts $arr_name:
  dict for {key val} [array get $arr_name] {
    puts "$key : $val"
  }
}

proc coll_gen container_name {
  generate [namespace code collect] $container_name
}

array set containerB {}
set container_name [namespace which -variable containerB]
foreach cmd {coll_gen dump} {$cmd $container_name}
```

A variable created (by assignment or the `variable` command) in the global scope will be a *namespace* variable that exists independent of stack frames: every proc in the program will be able to reach it using an absolute reference (such as created by `namespace which` or simply prepending the namespace to the variable name).

Local variables, OTOH, are disambiguated by name and stack frame. Within a stack frame, every use of a certain variable name will reference the same object. In the simple case, a proc will execute in one stack frame only, but the `uplevel` command may cause some piece of code to execute in another stack frame. In that case, the same name may be used to refer to different objects in the same code body. There is no ambiguity, though: the level of execution determines what object a name refers to.

When using the `upvar` command, two different name + stack frame permutations can be used to reference the same object residing on some stack level, or the same name can be used to reference objects from different stack levels:

```
proc foo {} {set abc foo ; bar}
proc bar {} {set abc bar ; baz}
proc baz {} {set abc baz ; qux}
proc qux {} {
    set abc qux
    foreach n {3 2 1 0} {
        upvar $n abc var
        lappend res $var
    }
    puts [join $res { }]
}
foo
# => foo bar baz qux
```

Again, there is never any ambiguity, since the name + stack level designation makes the identity of the object clear.

The `uplevel` and `upvar` commands can be wonderfully convenient as long as you can keep the stack frames straight, and I for one use them all the time. As you saw in Donal's answer, though, even a Tcl ace can't always keep the stack frames straight, and in those cases namespace variables are much simpler and safer.

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: This is really great explanation. I just don't understand: If everything is just passing around a string, without dragging the objects trough the stack, how then can safely be distinguished between identically named local variables in different levels of the stack? For example, if - in your solution - 'generate' would happen to have a local variable named 'containerB', and the containerB bound to container_name would also be a variable local to a proc, how does the eval in 'generate' know, which of the two different containerB variables should be used?

Comment: @user1934428: that's what the `namespace which` is for. The explanation is longish, so I'm putting it in the answer.